# SQLite How to add all string contents of a column to a single string (with condition)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app with SQLite and every row has a column of name strings and a column of checkers. Basically every person in my database has a name and a checker that shows if the person has applied to a course or not. The COLUMN_NAMES has stings like "ALEX", "JASON", etc and the COLUMN_CHECK has string like "YES" or "NO".

At the press of a button I want to generate a single string like "ALEX, JASON, WALTER, TOM, HEISENBERG" with only the names of those that have the COLUMN_CHECK value "YES".

Here is an image example if I did not make myself understood above:

[TABLE AND STRING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6lz7.png)

I have a DatabaseHelper class named CRUD.class and these are some key lines in my classes:

**Entries.class (data class):**

```
public static final String COLUMN_NAMES = "names";
public static final String COLUMN_CHECK = "check";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entries";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUM_NAMES + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_CHECK + " TEXT"
                + ")";

public Entry() {
}

public Entry(int id, String names, String check) {
    this.id = id;
    this.names = names;
    this.check = check;
}

public int getId() { return id; }
public void setId(int id){ this.id = id; }

public String getNames() { return names; }
public void setNames(String names){ this.names = names; }

public String getCheck() { return check; }
public void setCheck(String check){ this.check = check; }
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
  private EntryAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CRUD db;


        db = new CRUD(this);
        entryList.addAll(db.getAllEntries());

        mAdapter = new EntryAdapter(this, entryList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use SQLite's `GROUP_CONCAT` function here:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(names) AS names_csv
FROM entries
WHERE "check" = 'YES';
```

[image]

### Demo

Side note: Please *avoid* using SQLite keywords like `check` for your table and column names.  To make the above query work, you will have to escape `check` in double quotes.

Comment: doesn't help, I need to know how to implement this in my code

Comment: @RFM Yes, it does help, because you can execute this query from your Java code.  And quite likely it would be more efficient to this aggregation directly in SQLite versus bringing in all information to Java and aggregating there.